# Want to get Desktop Environment on VPS when accessed by web browser, how do I do it?

Tags: gnome, apache2, kde

When I access to my distant server VPS by IP address in a web browser, there is Apache defaukt page but I would like to set a Desktop Environment (KDE or Gnome) as the main page. Is it possible ? How to do it ?

Comment: You can't get the desktop environment when accessing the remote server via HTTP/HTTPS.  You're looking for something called 'VNC' which doesn't run by default and doesn't operate over a webpage.

Comment: ok Thanks, I see. How to set the starting process for the system on remote server load by default ? I have access only to command line on my VPS. Thanks in advance

Comment: VPSes don't have the desktop environment installed by default, so you may want to check with your VPS provider to determine if they used an Ubuntu Server or an Ubuntu Desktop image on the VPS.  If the VPS has less than a gigabyte of memory, you should avoid running the GUI at all.  (Servers and VPSes usually don't use the desktop environment).  (However, that's a different question than you are asking here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the desktop environment when accessing the remote server via HTTP/HTTPS. You're looking for something called 'VNC' which doesn't run by default and doesn't operate over a webpage.

The Desktop Environment is designed to operate self-contained from web browsers' abilities to access it.  Therefore, it doesn't have any 'web' interface you can use.  Attempting to use a web browser to get a VNC connection to your server is *dangerous* as well, because even if you set up VNC through HTTPS, on its own it is horribly insecure.

What you're looking for is, essentially, installing a VNC Server or setting up VNC on the Desktop GUI within the Server.  **However**, most VPSes do not come with the Desktop environment available, and unless you're paying for more than 1GB of RAM on the VPS, you will not be able to properly install or run the GUI either.

(In both cases, there's other questions on Ask Ubuntu which touch about how to do VNC, or install the GUI; however for your core question of "How do I get to the Desktop Environment when accessing the VPS via a web browser", the answer is in a nutshell "You can't in any reliable or secure way".)